# Alternate proof to showing sets have the same cardinality?

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-set-theory

The question is #18 from Fraleigh's "A First Course in Abstract Algebra"

> For any set $A$, finite or infinite, let $B^A$ be the set of all functions mapping $A$ into the set $B = \{0,1\}$. Show that the cardinality of $B^A$ is the same as the cardinality of the power set of $A$, denoted $ \mathcal{P}(A)$.

I have seen this question has been asked before, but my question is not how to prove this. I attempted to prove it before looking up how others have. Many others go about it by showing that a one-to-one mapping exists, but my proof goes with a more combinatorical approach, and I am wondering if it is a valid alternative to this proof.

My proof relies on the fact that $|\mathcal{P} (A) | = 2^n$ and constructing the set $B^A$ and showing how it must have the same number of elements.

## Proof

I let $A = \{a_0, a_1, a_2, \dots a_{s-1} \}$ be a set with cardinality $s$ and I let $B = \{0,1\}$. I also denote $B^A$ to be the set of all functions mapping $A$ to $B$. Since a function is a relation, this set $B^A$ needs to be a subset of the Cartesian product $A\times B$, which is equal to $$A\times B = \{ (a_0, 0), (a_0, 1), (a_1, 0), (a_1, 1), \dots (a_{s-1},0), (a_{s-1}, 1) \}$$

Now to have a function, we need to make sure each element in $A$ is represented only once as the beginning of one ordered pair. So we need to choose one with $a_0$ as the first member, one with $a_1$ as the first member, and so on, so that in total we will have all the possible combinations of function mappings. Since there are $2$ ways to choose each with $a_i$ as the first member of an ordered pair, and we have $s$ elements in $A$ (because it has cardinality $s$) we have the number of functions to be $2^s$. So the cardinality of $B^A$ is $2^s$.

After easily showing the power set of $A$ also has cardinality of $2^s$ via the binomial theorem, we are done.

---

Since I haven't seen anyone else prove it this way, it makes me wonder if this is valid. Any help would be greatly appreciated on telling me whether this works or not.

Comment: Your proof only works if the set $A$ is finite, while the theorem states that $A$ can be infinite.

Comment: @D. Brogan that was definitely one thing I wasn't sure about, hence giving me reason to ask in the first place